# Having a time-based line-chart sorted by time (x-axis) in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array, chart.js

Context:
I want to display a scoreboard for a game on a web page with ChartJS as a line-chart which would show the score progression (Y axis) along the time (X axis). Each line representing a team, nothing fancy, really.
My data-source is a JSON array of scores sorted by teams `[{team_A,[{timestamp01,score},{timestamp02,score}]},{team_A,[{timestamp01,score},{timestamp02,score}]},...]`. The array is extracted from a database and each record (a timestamp/score tuple) is generated when a team resolves a challenge.

Here's a minimal webpage with the code I'm using and some dummy data : https://jsfiddle.net/8sx3ykt0/

Problem :
The resulting line chart displays multiple timeline (one for each team) so the overall timeline (X-axis) isn't linear and thus the score progression (lines) from each time are kinda segregated from each other (no crossing) and thus it's not possible to see at a glance when a team's score got better than another one. I thought about sorting the X-axis values to solve that but currently there's [no such sorting solution built in ChartJS](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4862) after the data have been processed by it.

The other solution would be to build an array already sorted not by teams but by timestamp (so a team could have multiple entries in this array) before passing it to ChartJS, but as you can see in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/6vk1d0ez/) where I've added some points for "team 1" further away in the array, ChartJS doesn't interpret the "label" as an unique ID but displays multiple distinct lines with the same label, instead of pooling all the data in the same line (team).

My question :
How can I display with ChartJS such a scoreboard with a linear timeline and one line for each team?

Comment: You'll have to preprocess your data to make it to the format you want. The charts library will only display the datapoints where you say it should. In particular, it will not group datasets with the same label in one dataset. You can very easily do that in javascript. Also, I'd recommend using time on the x axis, rather than categories, (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u39gaLqr/)) and if the datasets are too far apart, then do something about it in preprocessing, that's also easier with timestamps than with strings.

Comment: Very interesting answer, thank you. It looks like the preprocessing for my data I've used is fine as I see in your answer you're using the same but I wasn't aware of the plugin [chart adapter fns](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-date-fns) you've added which overrides the default behaviour/date parsing of ChartJS thus enabling a linear time axis.

Comment: Right, with no `type` of the x scale specified, for `line` charts the default is [`"category"`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html). If you change its `type` to [`"time"`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) you start to get messages about an [adapter](https://github.com/chartjs/awesome#adapters) and other options missing.

Comment: Also, it doesn't combine datasets with the same label, neither does it sort data, although it may seem so for linear data, it's actually a line doubled going back and forth, see for instance [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9eczrhw/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The array I've got for each team is already sorted by timestamp so using the time adapter like you've suggested was enough for solving my issue since it basically merge all the timestamps in a coherent/linear timeline. I wasn't aware of the default category type applied to my x-axis but now all is clearer. Thanks again for your help !